# How to unset a fill color in css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, svg, fill

So I have this WONDERFULLY coded theme (as usual on wordpress) and to turnaround of a bug where it doesn't show the svg as supposed, i'm inserting it via html in the functions.php

all good, if not that the svg is made by different colors, and there's this css class from the theme which deliberately colors the whole fill parameters of the svg, with:

```
.my-stupid-svg-class path {
fill: purple
}
```

so, since each path in the svg code has its right color set (with `fill="yellow"` , ecc), what i tried at first was to "unset" that css class within my child-theme style.css, with something like:

```
.my-stupid-svg-class path {
fill: unset
}
```

I also tried initial and inherit but they all color the whole svg black. Any idea of how may i solve this without touching the theme css files? or as i update the theme it's all gone again

Comment: fill property can accept any CSS color value. so you can try fill:transparent

Comment: `fill: unset` should work. make sure you target correct class. try adding it in the browser's elements tab and see if it works.

Comment: Maybe use fill-opacity="0.0" as attribute on your svg?

Comment: These all make the svg disappear, i tried transparent before. I tried the "unset" via chrome inspection as well, with and without !important, but it makes all paths black

Comment: "Any idea of how may i solve this without touching the theme css files? or as i update the theme it's all gone again", create a [Child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and change stuff around to your heart's content.

Comment: Oh well, if there is no css solution to unset the fill i guess i'm going to dequeue those two css files with that class and queue my own version without it

Comment: Just a suggestion - I'm not sure if this will work - but have you tried `fill: inherit` instead of `fill: unset`? I'm happy to add this as a solution below if it does work.

Comment: Yes as i wrote i tried also inherit and initial, thanks anyway! also about the solution i think i'll take, to dequeue and enqueue my css version, is still not the best, since if the theme will update those two files with new stuff in the future, my wordpress will still dequeue them and enqueue my version which didn't have the new stuff in it

Comment: `unset` doesn’t work here, because you don’t actually want to unset - you want it to still _take_ the `fill="yellow"` values specified on the path elements, but your CSS overwrites those. Overwriting them with `unset`, effectively resolves to either `initial` or `inherit` – both not what you want. You want that CSS rule to not have existed in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe as i suspected, again, badly coded theme. I solved with dequeue on both the css files, and enqueued a copy of them without that class. not the best as i said, but better than changing the parent files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using !important ? fill: unset !important;

Answer (score 0):

Needed to fix this one today, answer is:

fill: revert-layer

Answer (score 0):

You could change the class name from `my-stupid-svg-class` to something else, like `my-other-stupid-svg-class`, so the rule will no longer apply to it. This is desirable if there are multiple rules you want to remove.

If you want to keep some of the rules, then it might make sense to have another class as well and define a more specific rule:

```
.my-stupid-svg-class.some-other-class path {
    fill: unset
}
```